# Struct within a union within a struct changes during function call

Tags: c, multithreading, function, struct

I'm working on a multithreaded producer-consumer program in c that implements semaphores. Each buffer struct has two general semaphores - one for empty buffers and one for full buffers. However, when the program enters the readInput function, the value of those two semaphores change to random values. The semaphore within the thread struct is fine, but the semaphores within the buffer struct within the IO union within the thread struct change for some reason. Any idea why this is happening?

```
#include "st.h"
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "buffer.h"

/*Definitions here*/
//Input location.
#define DEFAULT_IN stdin
//Output location.
#define DEFAULT_OUT stdout
//Line width
#define LINE_SIZE 80
#define SLEEP_TIME 333333

//Shorthand for structure components
#define INPUT thread->in
#define MUTEX thread->mutex
#define OUTPUT thread->out

/*Global variables here*/

//The input/output can be a stream or a buffer.
typedef union
{
    buffer *bufferIO;   //Buffer to read from/write to.
    FILE *stream;       //An I/O stream.
} IO;

//Each thread has an input, a semaphore, and an output.
typedef struct
{
        IO in;          //Either an input stream or a buffer to read.
        semaphore *mutex;   //Pointer to a binary semaphore.
        IO out;         //Either an output stream or a buffer to write.
} Thread;


/*Function prototypes here*/
void *readInput(void *s);
void *processLines(void *s);
void *processAsterisks(void *s);
void *writeOutput(void *s);

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])  //The main function  
{
    st_init();

    /*Binary semaphore*/
    semaphore mutex;        //Binary semaphore for mutual exclusion.
    createSem(&mutex, 1);

    printf("Beginning...\n");
    /*The three buffers between threads*/
    buffer B1, B2, B3;
    createBuf(&B1);
    createBuf(&B2);
    createBuf(&B3);

    /*The 5 data locations*/
    IO input, buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, output;    //stdin, 3 buffers, stdout

    /*Set the unions*/
    input.stream = DEFAULT_IN;  //Input stream
    buffer1.bufferIO = &B1;     //Contains raw input
    buffer2.bufferIO = &B2;     //Newlines have become spaces
    buffer3.bufferIO = &B3;     //** has become ^
    output.stream = DEFAULT_OUT;    //Output stream, 80 at a time

    /*Initialize the threads*/
        Thread input_thread = {input, &mutex, buffer1};         //Recieve input
        Thread proc1_thread = {buffer1, &mutex, buffer2};       //Returns to spaces
        Thread proc2_thread = {buffer2, &mutex, buffer3};       //** to ^
        Thread output_thread = {buffer3, &mutex, output};       //Output 80 characters and a newline.

    printf("%i\n", input_thread.out.bufferIO->emptyBuffers->value);
    /*Create the actual threads*/
    if(st_thread_create(readInput, &input_thread, 0, 0) == NULL)
    {
        perror("st_thread_create for input thread failure");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%i\n", input_thread.out.bufferIO->emptyBuffers->value);
    if(st_thread_create(processLines, &proc1_thread, 0, 0) == NULL)
    {
        perror("st_thread_create for line thread failure");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(st_thread_create(processAsterisks, &proc2_thread, 0, 0) == NULL)
    {
        perror("st_thread_create for asterisk thread failure");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(st_thread_create(writeOutput, &output_thread, 0, 0) == NULL)
    {
        perror("st_thread_create for output thread failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    st_thread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
/*Function definitions here*/
void *readInput(void *s)
{
    Thread *thread = s;
    char c;                 //An individual character.

    printf("Type some input.\n");
    do
    {
        down(MUTEX);
        c = getc(INPUT.stream);     //Consume a character from input.
    printf("%i\n", OUTPUT.bufferIO->emptyBuffers->value);
        deposit(OUTPUT.bufferIO, c);    //Produce a character.
        up(MUTEX);
        st_usleep(SLEEP_TIME);      //Wait.
    }
    while(c != EOF);            //Do-while in order to pass on the EOF as an exit flag.

    //EOF reached - exit thread.
    //assert(c == EOF);

    printf("\nDone reading.");
    st_thread_exit(NULL);
}...
```

Upon looking at it with gdb, I found this:

```
Hardware watchpoint 10: (*(*input_thread.out.bufferIO).emptyBuffers).value
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 10: (*(*input_thread.out.bufferIO).emptyBuffers).value

Old value = 80
New value = 4216725
0x000000395221467c in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Not sure what this _dl_runtime_resolve is.

Comment: I'd step through the code under your favorite debugger and see if any of your code is overwriting your semaphores.  "Watchpoints" might also be of use, if your debugger provides them.  IMHO...

Comment: Will st_thread_exit wait on the child threads to complete?  If not, it seems like your thread objects could go out of scope before readInput is executed.

Answer (score 0):

semaphore and buffers are created as stack variables in main thread so when the main thread exits the address pointing to semaphore and buffer are invalid and the behavior is unpredictable. Make the proper design and give proper scope to the variables, for time being make all the variables as global.  Make the following things in the above code as global

1. semaphore mutex;        //Binary semaphore for mutual exclusion.

   AND
2. IO input, buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, output;    //stdin, 3 buffers, stdout

recompile and execute

Comment: That's not at all an answer to the question that was asked